# combining two textbox values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i called a field from mysql into a readonly textarea and i made another textbox to allow users to add fields into the textarea. how do I combine the values from the textbox into the textarea?

an example of what i want to do is:

**textarea**

15/12: Nothing special today

16/12: another day

17/12: and so on

**textbox**

this is a new input

**Result**

15/12: Nothing special today

16/12: another day

17/12: and so on

18/12: this is a new input

The textarea is `"log1"` and the textbox is `"txb1"`. I'm currently using

```
log =  trim(request.form("log1"))
```

how do I do something like

```
log = trim(request.form("log1")) <br> date ": " trim(request.form("txb1"))
```

Comment: You want to do this on client side or on server side and push to db?

Comment: @SivaGopal `Request.Form` should give away its a serverside operation...

Comment: @Banana What I am wondering is, since he is using Asp.net, he could have used those textbox/textarea ids itself (e.g: txb1.Text). Why he is going that hard route of Request.Form? Did he have any client side html elements?

Comment: @SivaGopal you are right, if those are the id's then he could. maybe its just what floats his boat, adaptation from another language maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming `date` is a string variable, You would want to do the following:

```
log = trim(request.form("log1")) & "<br>" & [date] & ": " & trim(request.form("txb1"))
```

also, if `date` is a DateTime variable, you would want to use `date.ToShortDateString()` and instead of `<br/>` i would recommend using `Environment.NewLine`

and even better, you should use StringBuilder:

```
Dim SB As New StringBuilder()
SB.AppendLine(trim(request.form("log1")))
SB.AppendLine([date] & ": " & trim(request.form("txb1")))
log = SB.ToString()
```

**UPDATE:**

if you want to store the entire log in one record rather than a separate table, you better off saving it as a list of logs into a `varbinary(MAX)` column.

here is a full example of how to do it:

**1. we start by creating a `<div>` element that will hold our pretty logs and will be handled by the server, and a text box for new logs:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txb1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<div id="Text_Div1" runat="server"></div>
```

**2. now in the code behind, we create a class to hold 1 single line of log:**

```
'create a log class and state that it serializable 
<Serializable> _
Public Class MyLogRecord
    Public Sub New(_msg As String)
        [Date] = DateTime.Now
        Message = _msg
    End Sub
    Public Property [Date]() As DateTime
        Get
            Return m_Date
        End Get
        Set
            m_Date = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Date As DateTime
    Public Property Message() As [String]
        Get
            Return m_Message
        End Get
        Set
            m_Message = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Message As [String]
    Public Function ToText() As String
        Return [Date].ToShortDateString() & ": " & Convert.ToString(Message)
    End Function
End Class
```

**3. wherever you update the logs, whether its button_click or textbox_keydown, you do the following:**

```
' create a list of logs
Dim MyLogs As List(Of MyLogRecord)
'check if we stored the logs already in the session, 
'if yes, retrieve it from the session var,
'if not then create a new one.
If Session("MyLogs") IsNot Nothing Then
    MyLogs = DirectCast(Session("MyLogs"), List(Of MyLogRecord))
Else
    MyLogs = New List(Of MyLogRecord)()
End If
' create a new log record from the new textbox value
Dim _tempLog As New MyLogRecord(txb1.Text)
'add the new log to the list
MyLogs.Add(_tempLog)
'save it back in a session var:
Session("MyLogs") = MyLogs
```

**4. in the part where you save the logs to the mysql db, you do it this way: first convert the list to a byte array and store it in a `varbinary(MAX)` column**

```
'create a new binary formatter, include System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
Dim formatter As New BinaryFormatter()
'create a byte array to store our logs list
Dim _logsBinary As Byte()
'create a memory stream to write the logs list into
Using _logStream As New MemoryStream()
    'use the formatter to serialize the list in to an array of bytes 
    'directly into the memory stream
    formatter.Serialize(_logStream, MyLogs)
    'dump the memory stream into the byte array
    _logsBinary = _logStream.ToArray()
End Using
' ... save the _logsBinary into mysql as a 'varbinary(max)' ...
```

**5. in the place where you retrieve the logs from the mysql db, you de-serialize the byte array back to a logs list:**

```
Dim MyLogs As New List(Of MyLogRecord)()
Dim formatter As New BinaryFormatter()
Using _logStream As New MemoryStream()
    _logStream.Write(_logsBinary, 0, _logsBinary.Length)
    _logStream.Position = 0
    ' de-serialize the byte array back into a logs list
    MyLogs = DirectCast(formatter.Deserialize(_logStream), List(Of MyLogRecord))
End Using
```

**6. in the place where you write the logs in your page, you do it this way:**

```
Dim SB As New StringBuilder()
' create a temp date to compare against all the records,
' and initialize it with the first value or else you will have 
' a orizontal line before the first row
Dim _prevDate As DateTime = MyLogs.First().[Date]
For Each _logRec As MyLogRecord In MyLogs
    'take the date of the currently iterrated item and
    'compare against the temp date, note that comparing months is not enough, 
    'month might be same/earlier but year can be higher
    Dim _currentDate As DateTime = _logRec.[Date]
    If _currentDate.Month > _prevDate.Month OrElse _currentDate.Year > _prevDate.Year Then
        'append horizontal line
        SB.AppendLine("<hr/>")
        'update temp value
        _prevDate = _currentDate
    End If
    'finally append the log: ToText() is the class custom
    'function that we created above
    SB.AppendLine(_logRec.ToText())
Next

'dump the logs into the server managed div:
Text_Div1.InnerHtml = SB.ToString()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is there a way to make the <br> function like enter? coz now it just writes <br>

Comment: environment.newline, and the string builder should take care of that. for the string builder you will need to include `System.Text`

Comment: Works Great! Thanks! one more question, is there a way to add in a horizontal line?

Comment: If you are planning to show the data as an html part on your page, just append an "<hr/>". I think you cannot do it with a asp:TextArea, but you can with asp:Literal or just put a div with a runat=server

Comment: I actually wanted to separate the logs by month. meaning a line just before the start of each month. if it's not possible I could just do ___ manually.

Comment: in that case, you need to store the logs in an custom object rather than a string, and just print them out as a string. would make life easier. i can make a short example in a bit. or since  you are using an sql database, you should create a separate table for logs and then just print them out month by month separated by a horizontal rule

Comment: Thanks for the example. I didn't know that it could be stored in a session. Will try it out later. btw, I've still got a few questions not related to this. can I email you or something?

Comment: sure mate, glad i could help. and it would be much better if you post your questions here on SO, they might help other programmers in the future and you will have a better chance of receiving an answer here with millions of programmers reading it daily +i might not be available for weeks.